# Web of Trust: What is "signatory trust"?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, pgp, web-of-trust

I am learning about the Web of Trust and how to use it. However, I have some issues to fully grasp the concept of *Signatory Trust*.

What is an easily understandable definition of *signatory trust*? An example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Signatory Trust

**Signatory trust is used to describe the situation of transitive certifications.** Consider Alice signed Bob `Alice -> Bob`, and also puts owner trust on Bob (owner trust means, Alice puts faith in certification Bob issues). Now, if Bob signs Carol `Bob -> Carol` (but Alice doesn't), Alice cannot *directly* verify Carol's key (she didn't certify it herself), but she can build a *trust path*:

```
Alice -> Bob -> Carol
```

Remember that these transient trust steps always require three components, a **certification from a trusted and already valid key**. PGP/GnuPG use a [more advanced trust model](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41208/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-this-gpg-output-regarding-trust/41209#41209) with marginal and full trust, but the basic principle is the same.

### Trust Categories in the Example

In this situation, we have different kinds of trust:

- **trust in identity** (Alice is sure about Bob's key ownership, and Bob is sure about Carol's key ownership)
- **owner trust**: do I trust the key's owner to certify other keys? (Alice trusts Bob's certifications)
- **key validity** (the German Wikipedia uses "legitimacy" here): Is there a trust path to the other key, based on the first two kinds of trust?

  - trust path from Alice to herself is trivial (same for Bob to Bob and Carol to Carol)
  - direct trust from Alice to Bob, and Bob to Carol
  - **signatory trust**: transient trust path from Alice to Carol, over Bob's *trusted and valid* key
  - Bob cannot put trust on Alice' key, Carol can neither trust Alice nor Bob  (no trust paths)