# Are PGP/GnuPG trust information transferred to key servers?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, web-of-trust

When signing a key **X** in the PGP Web of Trust model, I assign the key full validity. **Other** people who have my key in their key ring can regard X as valid as far as they fully trust me (owner trust).

This mechanism only works if people *know* which key I have signed. Can I assume that such signing information is stored on key servers? Does this mean that I have to resend my key to a key server after having signed someone's key?

I am a little bit confused, because in "[What is the exact meaning of this gpg output regarding trust?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41208/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-this-gpg-output-regarding-trust)" the first answer contains the statement that

> ... trust is a kind of signature on other keys, it does not get distributed when uploading keys to key servers.

I would not understand how the PGP trust model works if this was true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This mechanism only works if people know which key I have signed. Can I assume that such signing information is stored on key servers?

Yes, certifications are stored on key servers.

> Does this mean that I have to resend my key to a key server after having signed someone's key?

You have to upload a key, but not yours, instead upload the certified key (or ship it to the owner, who can decide whether to upload it or not).

---

You have to differentiate between different kinds of trust.

### Certifications (Signatory Trust)

**OpenPGP expects trust in identity to be public, thus certifications being shared.** "I believe that Alice is really who she claims to be" is a statement based on facts that can be shared without further implications (maybe apart from network analysis and clustering being possible).

### Owner Trust

On the other, you have to decide whom to trust. Certifications issued are only valid, if a key itself is valid (so you can build a trust path to the other user) and you put trust in the certifications of all the users in-between (or partial trust on different paths). ["There's Trust and Then There's Trust and Then There's Trust](http://web.archive.org/web/20131009142806/https://www.rubygems-openpgp-ca.org/blog/theres-trust-and-then-theres-trust-and-then-theres-trust.html") (a nice article on trust in OpenPGP) called this "trust to vouch".

**Sharing this kind of trust might have heavy implications.** You don't trust in the capabilities to correctly certify others of your boss, wife/husband? They might get this *very wrong*. It also reveals social connections at a much deeper level, as you have to know the other person to some extend, while you can safely certify a completely stranger's identity by verifying his identity card/passport.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously there are two ways to sign a key. Either you can do this with _gpg --sign-key_ or first you select a key with _gpg --edit-key uid_ and then type "sign". Is there any difference? I chose the second way and now wonder how to to send this information to a key server.

Comment: I just found the answer: –sign-key name

"Sign a public key with you secret key. This is a shortcut version of the subcommand "sign" from –edit."

Comment: Exactly. Trust is issued by running `--edit-key` and a subsequent `trust`.

Comment: Do I have to manually upload each newly signed key or is there a command to upload all recently changed keys?

Comment: `--send-keys` does not require an argument and uploads all public keys. But there might be people around that are _not_ happy if you do so, and want control over their public key (personally, I don't care who uploads my key).

Comment: UPDATE: The default keyserver for most tools is now `keys.openpgp.org` which does not allow clients to retrieve keys containing signatures from others (only self-signatures made by the primary key).  All data that would be necessary for the W.O.T. is stripped.