# How can I verify if a person is in my web of trust?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, digital-signature, pgp, web-of-trust

Lets say I trust person A (whose public key is in a key server) and I want to know if I can also trust person B (pub key is also in a key server).

How can I verify that I have a chain of trust between person A and B? Or better: that can verify if there is a chain from any person that I trust to person B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validating keys means finding a path based on certifications, where all intermediate keys are also valid. This requires valid (there is a trust path to those keys) and trusted (they are considered for validating other keys) intermediate keys, and certifications issued by those keys (which for the edges between the keys).

> How can I verify that I have a chain of trust between person A and B?

GnuPG will do this for you: it will calculate the trusted part of your local view on the web of trust based on certifications and configured trust.

> Or better: that can verify if there is a chain from any person that I trust to person B?

For the general case, this requires knowledge of the whole OpenPGP web of trust. The [PGP pathfinder](http://pgp.cs.uu.nl/) is a website doing exactly this for you without having to store a local dump of all keys. Using the [wotsap](http://pgp2.cs.uu.nl/wotsap/) software, you can also do this locally, but it is rather involving.

Both applications only list *possible* trust paths, but these provide support at validating intermediate keys within GnuPG (and issuing trust on the go) until you have been able to validate the target key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about those tools, thank you for that. Now I have to figure it out how can I see the trust calculation of gpg from my local view.

Comment: While not immediately fit for your task, [I discussed GnuPG's output on information to the web of trust some time ago](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/41208/19837).